# Glass Door scrapping ( selenium) , Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, spyder, data-collection

I'm trying to scrape Glassdoor, While executing the code, there are no errors and the website opens, but then nothing happens.  I've tried changing the tags but it's still working.

The problem is that I want to click the first selected JOB but it's not working, also  I tried :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MainCol"]/div[1]/ul/li[1]')
```

Here's the code snippet:

```
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd


def get_jobs(keyword, num_jobs, verbose, path, slp_time):
    
    '''Gathers jobs as a dataframe, scraped from Glassdoor'''
    
    #Initializing the webdriver
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    
    #Uncomment the line below if you'd like to scrape without a new Chrome window every time.
    #options.add_argument('headless')
    
    #Change the path to where chromedriver is in your home folder.
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options)
    driver.set_window_size(1120, 1000)
    
    url = "https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/jobs.htm?suggestCount=0&suggestChosen=false&clickSource=searchBtn&typedKeyword="+keyword+"&sc.keyword="+keyword+"&locT=&locId=&jobType="
    #url = 'https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/jobs.htm?sc.keyword="' + keyword + '"&locT=C&locId=1147401&locKeyword=San%20Francisco,%20CA&jobType=all&fromAge=-1&minSalary=0&includeNoSalaryJobs=true&radius=100&cityId=-1&minRating=0.0&industryId=-1&sgocId=-1&seniorityType=all&companyId=-1&employerSizes=0&applicationType=0&remoteWorkType=0'
    driver.get(url)
    jobs = []

    while len(jobs) < num_jobs:  #If true, should be still looking for new jobs.

        #Let the page load. Change this number based on your internet speed.
        #Or, wait until the webpage is loaded, instead of hardcoding it.
        time.sleep(slp_time)

        #Test for the "Sign Up" prompt and get rid of it.
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_class_name("selected").click()
        except ElementClickInterceptedException:
            pass

        time.sleep(.1)

        try:
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[alt="Close"]').click() #clicking to the X.
            print(' x out worked')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print(' x out failed')
            pass

        
        #Going through each job in this page
        job_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("jl")  #jl for Job Listing. These are the buttons we're going to click.
        for job_button in job_buttons:  

            print("Progress: {}".format("" + str(len(jobs)) + "/" + str(num_jobs)))
            if len(jobs) >= num_jobs:
                break

            job_button.click()  #You might 
            time.sleep(1)
            collected_successfully = False
            
            while not collected_successfully:
                try:
                    company_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="employerName"]').text
                    location = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="location"]').text
                    job_title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "title")]').text
                    job_description = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="jobDescriptionContent desc"]').text
                    collected_successfully = True
                except:
                    time.sleep(5)

            try:
                salary_estimate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="gray salary"]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                salary_estimate = -1 #You need to set a "not found value. It's important."
            
            try:
                rating = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="rating"]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                rating = -1 #You need to set a "not found value. It's important."

            #Printing for debugging
            if verbose:
                print("Job Title: {}".format(job_title))
                print("Salary Estimate: {}".format(salary_estimate))
                print("Job Description: {}".format(job_description[:500]))
                print("Rating: {}".format(rating))
                print("Company Name: {}".format(company_name))
                print("Location: {}".format(location))

            #Going to the Company tab...
            #clicking on this:
            #<div class="tab" data-tab-type="overview"><span>Company</span></div>
            try:
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="tab" and @data-tab-type="overview"]').click()

                try:
                    #<div class="infoEntity">
                    #    <label>Headquarters</label>
                    #    <span class="value">San Francisco, CA</span>
                    #</div>
                    headquarters = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Headquarters"]//following-sibling::*').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    headquarters = -1

                try:
                    size = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Size"]//following-sibling::*').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    size = -1

                try:
                    founded = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Founded"]//following-sibling::*').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    founded = -1

                try:
                    type_of_ownership = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Type"]//following-sibling::*').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    type_of_ownership = -1

                try:
                    industry = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Industry"]//following-sibling::*').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    industry = -1

                try:
                    sector = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Sector"]//following-sibling::*').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    sector = -1

                try:
                    revenue = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Revenue"]//following-sibling::*').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    revenue = -1

                try:
                    competitors = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Competitors"]//following-sibling::*').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    competitors = -1

            except NoSuchElementException:  #Rarely, some job postings do not have the "Company" tab.
                headquarters = -1
                size = -1
                founded = -1
                type_of_ownership = -1
                industry = -1
                sector = -1
                revenue = -1
                competitors = -1

                
            if verbose:
                print("Headquarters: {}".format(headquarters))
                print("Size: {}".format(size))
                print("Founded: {}".format(founded))
                print("Type of Ownership: {}".format(type_of_ownership))
                print("Industry: {}".format(industry))
                print("Sector: {}".format(sector))
                print("Revenue: {}".format(revenue))
                print("Competitors: {}".format(competitors))
                print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@")

            jobs.append({"Job Title" : job_title,
            "Salary Estimate" : salary_estimate,
            "Job Description" : job_description,
            "Rating" : rating,
            "Company Name" : company_name,
            "Location" : location,
            "Headquarters" : headquarters,
            "Size" : size,
            "Founded" : founded,
            "Type of ownership" : type_of_ownership,
            "Industry" : industry,
            "Sector" : sector,
            "Revenue" : revenue,
            "Competitors" : competitors})
            #add job to jobs
            
            
        #Clicking on the "next page" button
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//li[@class="next"]//a').click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print("Scraping terminated before reaching target number of jobs. Needed {}, got {}.".format(num_jobs, len(jobs)))
            break

    return pd.DataFrame(jobs)  #This line converts the dictionary object into a pandas DataFrame.
```

Comment: Try `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MainCol"]/div[1]/ul/li[1]//a[@data-test='job-link']')`

Comment: not working Invalid Syntax

Comment: xpath syntax is 100% valid: https://i.imgur.com/Uw6oPQT.png

Comment: @AndreyKotov  the xpath syntax may have been valid but you used single quotes in the string without escaping them. I think you meant `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MainCol"]/div[1]/ul/li[1]//a[@data-test=\'job-link\']')`?

Comment: Yeah, maybe. I am not a python user. Most likely this would work: `"//*[@id='MainCol']/div[1]/ul/li[1]//a[@data-test='job-link']"`

Answer (score 0):

```
 try:
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,  '[data- 
selected="true"]').click()
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        pass
```

Perhaps this may work? Selenium did change their find_element formatting (somewhat recently) so keep that in mind for the rest of your work as well.